# Can I receive any video call through appium?

Tags: mobile, automation, automated-tests, whatsapp, appium-android

for end to end automation, I need to receive video call on my android device by using appium. Is this possible through Appium. please advice any one done it before OR having any solution for the same.

Thanks in advance